# Can a PHP extension be used to make calls to a C++ DLL?

Tags: php, c++, php-extension

I have C++ library that I would like to use to create a PHP extension.
I don't have anything besides the compiled DLL file.

I would just like to know if this is possible or does it need to be a C library?

Comment: If you can do something with C library it is possible with C++ library also

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, You can build extension using C++ libraries.

There is a very good example describing the process here : http://devzone.zend.com/1435/wrapping-c-classes-in-a-php-extension/